# Is it possible to set up Storm API on a single machine

Tags: maven, installation, local, apache-storm

I am trying to figure out if it's possible to set up the whole [storm project](http://storm-project.net/about/simple-api.html) on a single machine for testing and simulation purposes, so this question is mainly to those who tried this.I know that with Hadoop (which is what Storm was based of) allows the ability to simulate a cluster.I have read something about Maven and how it could be used to run Storm locally,but not really sure of what Maven is and how it would really work.I hope somebody around here can help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes this is possible.  You can stand up a "single-node cluster" for Storm to run on, and it can be all on a single machine.  This would emulate what a real cluster would be like, but you would have 1 machine hosting the entire stack (ZooKeeper & Storm).  Essentially the Nimbus server is your worker server.  Configuring this is the same as following this guide here:  https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Setting-up-a-Storm-cluster.  Essentially everything will be your localhost machine.

Maven is a build tool, used to build software from source (it can do other things as well, like deploying and releasing it).  In this case, I recommend getting the [storm-starter project from github](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-starter) and using this to get your feet wet with storm.  The maven command that you would run after getting the starter project would be something like this:

```
$ mvn -f m2.pom compile exec:java -Dexec.classpathScope=compile -Dexec.mainClass=com.some.package.name.YourMainTopologyClass
```

Note that you could just as easily use lein to get it going as well.

So, to summarize:

1. Yes you can stand up what would be a "single-node cluster" of Storm and use to send topologies to run.
2. Yes you can use Maven to execute a Storm Topology.  Note that the storm-starter is really what you should be playing with to get an idea of how this works.  Notice in some of the examples the Topologies they build and use end up getting submitted to a `LocalCluster`.  This is ideal for development & testing of Topologies, and [essentially simulates a Storm Cluster](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Local-mode) in-process for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,I was reading some posts people made on various forums and some of them said you can just include storm in the class path when building the project in maven and it would essentially run the storm cluster in memory,any idea if this might be true? The problem is that I am working on a windows machine.

Comment: @Tohmas - this sounds like what the maven command above does:  runs an "in-memory" emulated storm cluster (LocalCluster).  In this case, the storm libs would be listed as dependencies in the Maven pom file (in the starter-project's case, m2.pom).  If you have another project that you wish to use Storm with, you would list Storm as a dependency just like the m2.pom does.  I recommend downloading the storm-starter project, and using that as a template to make your project's changes on.  That way, all the maven plumbing is done for you (pom files).